# rosmake cannot find protobuf while making gazebo_worlds in fuerte

Tags: gazebo, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am using 'fuerte' on CentOS 64-bit (~ RHEL 6). I am trying to build gazebo_worlds using rosmake, but it fails with the following error:

[rospack] Error: package/stack gazebo depends on non-existent package protobuf

I installed protobuf myself and it exists in a 'lib' dir which is visible to rosmake. The .h files are in an 'include' directory also visible to rosmake. I also have the protobuf egg file in the python site-packages. Then from a post online, I came to know I have to add the following line to .rosinstall, but still the error exists:

- tar: {local-name: protobuf, uri: 'https://code.ros.org/svn/release/download/stacks/protobuf/protobuf-0.1.0/protobuf-0.1.0.tar.bz2',
version: protobuf-0.1.0}

Thanks in advance,
dksr

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37368/rosmake-cannot-find-protobuf-while-making-gazebo_worlds-in-fuerte/) by [Krishna Dubba](https://answers.ros.org/users/2103/krishna-dubba/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2012-06-27

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In fuerte Gazebo expects protobuf installed on the system not as a ROS package.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0